# Filtering on multiple values from a single field - Django

Tags: python, django

```
myprefs = aboutme.mypreferences_set.all()[0]
mygpref = myprefs.MyGPref.all()
```

mygpref has a range of values and I'd like to return a QuerySet based on on these filters. I don't know how many values there may be in mygprefs. Might be one or two. How should I build a filter the pythonic way without lots of if and thens - I tried the below but this does not work for multiple values exist in mygpref.

```
mylist = AboutMe.objects.all().filter(MyG=mygpref)
```

How to do this elegantly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I had forgotten about this:

```
mylist = AboutMe.objects.all().filter(MyG__in=mygpref)
```

This seems to work..